# Прошу помочь сгруппировать одинаковые значение в строке pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

Есть следующий dataframe состоящий из одинаковых строк.

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Оператор фронтального погрузчика |
| 2 | Оператор фронтального погрузчика |
| 3 | Продавец продовольственных товаров |
| 4 | Продавец продовольственных товаров |
| 5 | Оператор фронтального погрузчика |

Необходимо добавить столбец 'group' следующего вида

| id | name | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Оператор фронтального погрузчика | 1 |
| 2 | Оператор фронтального погрузчика | 1 |
| 3 | Продавец продовольственных товаров | 2 |
| 4 | Продавец продовольственных товаров | 2 |
| 5 | Оператор фронтального погрузчика | 1 |

Comment: А сколько разных типов name в датафрейме? Я так понимаю group надо задавать значение на основе данных из столбца name? Поправьте пожалуйста таблицы, а то не особо понятно)

Comment: name - может быть бесконечным множеством. Главное, что если значение одинаковое присвоить одинаковую группу, все последующие группы будут + 1

Comment: Ну если в таблицу не будет добавляться новые типы name, то можно создать доп датафрейм, в котором будет 2 столбца name со списком всех возможных типов name с помощью .unique(), затем добавить к этому доп датафрейму столбец group и с помощью .apply() заполнить каждую строчку значениями больше предыдущей строчки на 1, затем можно объединить эти таблицы по столбцу name, таким образом в оригинальном датафрейме появится столбец group с нужными значениями. Ща попробую сделать

Comment: У меня изначально есть конечное число профессий. Я создал функцию, которая показывает мне все повторяющиеся значения и вот осталось все это сгруппировать. excel_data = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(excel_data, columns=['id','name'])
print(df)

ids = df['name']
dublicate=df[ids.isin(ids[ids.duplicated()])]

print(dublicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверняка есть более элегантные способы, но я смог так:

```
l_help = [] #список с номерами для каждой уникальной профессии
for i in range(1, len(df['name'].unique())+1):
    l_help.append(i) # заполнение списка номерами
df_help = pd.DataFrame({'name': df['name'].unique(), 'group': l_help}) # датафрейм в котором хранятся уникальные пары профессия-номер
df = pd.merge(left=df, right=df_help, on='name') # объединение в 1 датафрейм
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большее все отлично работает!!!

Comment: @DenisDark не за что)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, если данные уже представлены в Pandas, значит скорее всего - это DataFrame.  Как вам уже писали, на этом сайте принято данные представлять так, что-бы другие могди легко промоделировать ваш скрипт. Странно, что вы этого не сделали, ну да ладно, наверное вы очень заняты:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                  'name':['Оператор фронтального погрузчика',
                  'Оператор фронтального погрузчика',
                  'Продавец продовольственных товаров',
                  'Продавец продовольственных товаров',
                  'Оператор фронтального погрузчика']})
```

После этого задача решается в одну строчку:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
df1['group']= preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df1['name'])
```

Результат:

```
   id                                name  group
0   1    Оператор фронтального погрузчика      0
1   2    Оператор фронтального погрузчика      0
2   3  Продавец продовольственных товаров      1
3   4  Продавец продовольственных товаров      1
4   5    Оператор фронтального погрузчика      0
```

Или, если группы вам надо именно 1,2,3.... то вот так:

```
df1['group']= preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df1['name'])+1

   id                                name  group
0   1    Оператор фронтального погрузчика      1
1   2    Оператор фронтального погрузчика      1
2   3  Продавец продовольственных товаров      2
3   4  Продавец продовольственных товаров      2
4   5    Оператор фронтального погрузчика      1
```

И никаких дополнительных DataFrame и извращений с циклами.

Comment: Можно без доп. библиотек: `df['group'] = df.name.rank(method='dense').astype(int)`

Comment: Добрый вечер. Спасибо Вам всем за помощь, я новичок здесь и у меня совсем мало опыта в размещении вопросов, но в следующий раз я буду внимательнее. К сожалению вариант passant  мне не удалось проверить по причине, того что после установки библиотеки sklearn. Pycharm ругается на No module named 'sklearn'. Алексей Р, ваше решение также подходит, спасибо.